# Why does assigning a union member in the copy constructors crash?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, unions

I am writing a class which stores one of several data types via a union (in this case `QBrush` and `int`) and remembers which is active by using the `type` member.

```
class X
{
public:
    X(const QBrush &brush)
        : type(0), b(brush) { }
    X(int integer)
        : type(1), i(integer) { }
    X(const X &other)
        : type(other.type)
    {
        if (type == 0)
            b = other.b;
        else i = other.i;
    }

    ~X() { }

private:
    int type;
    union
    {
        QBrush b;
        int i;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    X x = X(QBrush(Qt::red));
    X y = X(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I was very surprised that this program crashes. Currently I have no debugger, so I only know it crashes inside the copy constructor of `X` when assigning the brush. Note that it works when I replace the copy constructor code with

```
X(const X &other)
    : type(other.type), b(other.b), i(other.i)
{ }
```

which is even more confusing for me.

`QBrush` is some class provided by Qt. I guess the crash has something to do with the internals of this class. But I have no idea. Does someone know what is going on?

Comment: Hint : a copy assignment operates on an existing object. Where has `b` been constructed before `b = other.b`?

Comment: I suspect QBrush has non-trivial constructor. In this case you need to create  the special members (ctors, assisgn ops, dtors) for the union

Comment: Also, for a quick and proper solution, see `std::variant` (or `boost::variant` if your standard library isn't up-to-date).

Comment: @Quentin I know about `std::variant` but sadly I cannot use the latest version of the std. I see the problem with the assignment, so should I use placement new instead?

Comment: I reckon so. --

Comment: @bolov If some of these functions is missing but is needed, shouldn't the program not compile instead of crash?

Comment: @Quentin Thank you very much for your quick help.

Comment: @M.Winter ohh... the innocence... Haaave you... met C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bug:

```
X(const X &other)
    : type(other.type)
{
    if (type == 0)
        b = other.b;  // b is not constructed yet
    else i = other.i;
}
```

`b` is not constructed yet, but you call `operator=` on it.

Use `new(&b) QBrush(other.b)`, which correctly constructs `b` with the copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you use [`boost::variant<QBrush, int>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/variant.html) / [`std::variant<QBrush, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17) instead of trying to manage this yourself. When placing a non-POD type in a union, you must handle the construction and destruction manually, and you are currently missing a few cases. At the very least, you need a custom destructor, and the rule of 3 says you should provide an assignment operator in addition to your copy constructor.

```
X(const X &other) : type(1) {
    *this = other;
}
~X() {
    if (type == 0) b.~QBrush();
}
X& operator=(const X &other) {
    if (type == 0) b.~QBrush();
    type = 1;
    if (other.type == 0) {
        new(&b) QBrush(other.b);
        type = 0;
    } else i = other.i;
    return *this;
}
```

Here, I've shifted around the assignment of `type` so that if the `QBrush` constructor throws an exception, we avoid calling the destructor on it when unwinding.